# Visual Studio 2010 Memory Window font

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fonts

I am using a proportional font (Cambria) in my VS2010 editor.  This is superb for writing code but it seems the same font is also used in the Memory window during debugging.  The memory window needs a fixed-width font to be useful but I can't find an option to set this.  Can anyone help?

**Update:**  I have reported this to Microsoft and the issue was promptly deferred.  If you voted for this question, please also upvote my request here:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696196/visual-studio-2010-memory-window-badly-aligned-when-proportional-font-used-in-text-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a workaround. Customise a 4-pack of http://input.fontbureau.com/ - very nice proportional font for coding, I'm using the sans.

- set proportional for the non-bold, not-bold italics
- set monospace for the bold, bold italics

Download the pack and install to Windows. May need to reboot after.
In visual studio, set bold for the memory window data. Voila- code in gorgeous proportional, memory dump in mono!

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible because the settings for the memory window are in fact a list of "Display Items" in the section for "Text Editor" (Memory Address, Memory Changed, Memory Data, Memory Unreadable). So you can differentiate the background and foreground color, but not the font.

Comment: I know it's not possible via the GUI but am now looking for any hacks or workarounds.  E.g. registry settings.  At a push, it might be OK to have a macro that changes the editor font whilst memory window is visible.

Comment: @paperjam - I have also monitored the registry. There is nothing available in the registry. This settings is located here HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\FontAndColors\{A27B4E24-A735-4D1D-B8E7-9716E1E3D8E0} but devenv.exe does not look for anything else than what you'll see there. And the automation object available to the macros only expose what you'll see in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Not in front of my pc right now so this is from memory...

Tools-Options-Font and colors-Debugging windows-Memory

Comment: Yes, you would think so but it does not seem possible to set a different font for memory window and text editor.